# Binding DataGrid to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, datagrid

In WPF I would like to load an Excel file with table containing date in first column and some data in the others. I would like to split that "xls" to several collection of Date-value data, the algorithm is quite easy and have it done already, but:
Now, I have

```
public class XYPoint: INotifyPropertyChanged
```

with all implementations. Then

```
public class XYManager
{
public ObservableCollection<XYPoint> XYPoints {get;set}
public string SeriesName{get;private set;}
}
```

and finally class, which contains source (xls) data and parses it to:

```
public class DataManager
{
 public ObservableCollection<XYManager> Data { get => _data; }
}
```

In MainWindow I have object `DataManager _dm;` and after the import of excel file is executed, Data are fill with parsed data, then:

```
 lstTables.ItemsSource = _dm.Data; //ListView
 dgImported.DataContext = _dm.Data; //DataGrid
```

corresponding part of XAML:

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstTables" ItemsSource="{Binding SeriesName}" SelectedItem="{Binding XYPoints}"/>
                        <DataGrid x:Name="dgImported" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding XYPoints}"/>
```

What I want is when user change the selection in ListView, the Datagrid should be automatically updated from the corresponding XYManager

Thanks in advance
Jan

Comment: you need to raise a property change event when you are setting the XYPoints collection in your XYManager class. Atleast from what i see that could be the problem.

Comment: Hi,
I try to specify my question better: I need to do the following:
 `private void lstTables_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lstTables.SelectedIndex >=0 )
            {
                dgImported.ItemsSource = _dm.Data[lstTables.SelectedIndex].XYPoints;
            }
        }`
using binding

Comment: this would work i think. but all this can be done with MVVM from the viewmodel if the class that contains the property that keeps changing(selected item) implements inotifypropertychanged and invokes the property changed event when the selection changes